# I need to validate email addresses which can be single or several comma-separated ones with semicolon or . optional in the last of email id

Tags: regex

I need to validate email addresses which can be single or several comma-separated ones with semicolon or . optional in the last of email id. I have used below regex for single email id which works perfectly:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Comment: Since you already have one that works, consider _splitting_ the input before validating.

Comment: Have a look at any related link displayed on the right banner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quantifier over the single e-mail regex:

```
(emailregex[;]?)+
```

or:

```
(emailregex)(;emailregex)*
```